# htaccess - redirect non https & set different default page for each sub-domain

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, https, subdomain

I have a wild card ssl for my domain. I have many subdomains each with its own default page.

www.domain.com/main.html       [/home/domain/main.html]
try.domain.com/free.php             [/home/domain/try/free.php]
new.domain.com/signup.php      [/home/domain/new/signup.php]
etc

I want to write .htaccess such that:

1. All traffic is directed to https
2. The subdomains resolve to respective default pages
3. All non-www is directed to www  except for the subdomains which remain subdomain.domain.com

I want to do all this in a single htaccess /home/domain/.htacces and not have htaccess files in each folder.

Answer (score 2):

IMHO You're already heading the wrong direction with your intention to create a `.htaccess` file, which is  my pet peeve, quoted from from the [manual on .htaccess](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/howto/htaccess.html#when) files:

> You should **avoid using `.htaccess` files completely** *if you have access to httpd main server config* file. Using **`.htaccess` files slows down your Apache http server**. Any directive that you can include in a `.htaccess` file is better set in a [`Directory`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#directory) block in the main Apache configuration file(s), as it will have the same effect with better performance.

Set up a default/catchall VirtualHost on port 80 for plain HTTP to the redirect to everything to your secure hosts:

```
<VirtualHost :80>
  Servername www.example.com
  ServerAlias *.example.com
  # https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/RewriteHTTPToHTTPS
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
  RewriteRule ^/?(.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R,L]

  >other optional directives<
</VirtualHost>
```

The above will preserve the hostname when redirecting to SSL.

Then much more effective configuration is to use the fact that you have a wildcard SSL certificate (and you don't even need to depend on SNI) and  [create a Name Virtual Host  for each of your subdomains](https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/NameBasedSSLVHosts), with a last catch-all that for any subdomain not explicitly defined redirects to www

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
        SSLEngine on
        >>other optional and required (SSL) directives<<
        SSLCertificateFile      /etc/ssl/star.example.com.crt
        SSLCertificateKeyFile   /etc/ssl/star.example.com.key
        ServerName      "one.example.com"
        DocumentRoot    "/var/www/html/one"
</virtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:443>
        SSLEngine on
        >>other optional and required (SSL) directives<<
        SSLCertificateFile      /etc/ssl/star.example.com.crt
        SSLCertificateKeyFile   /etc/ssl/star.example.com.key
        ServerName      "two.example.com"
        DocumentRoot    "/var/www/html/two"
</virtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:443>
        SSLEngine on
        >>other optional and required (SSL) directives<<
        SSLCertificateFile      /etc/ssl/star.example.com.crt
        SSLCertificateKeyFile   /etc/ssl/star.example.com.key
        ServerName      "www.example.com"
        DocumentRoot    "/var/www/html/www"
</virtualHost>

# Use the fact that the configuration file is parsed in order
# and make this catch-all entry only catch what isn't defined above:
<VirtualHost *:443>
        SSLEngine on
        >>other optional and required (SSL) directives<<
        SSLCertificateFile      /etc/ssl/star.example.com.crt
        SSLCertificateKeyFile   /etc/ssl/star.example.com.key
        ServerName      "star.example.com"
        ServerAlias      *.example.com
        Redirect / https://www.example.com
</virtualHost>
```

Or if you're into minimal configurations: [mod_vhost_alias](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_vhost_alias.html) may be of interest.

Comment: Unfortunately I dont have access to httpd config. I got to do this using htaccess. Thanks